# How to redirect the broken link to 404 page in htacces

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Hi i want to redirect to 404 page through `.htaccess` file. My 404 file is under includes folder with the name  of 404.php and `.htaccess` file is in root. This is the code i am writing in `.htaccess` file but nothing work yet.

```
#Turn On Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Rewrite folder
RewriteRule ^llapp/(.*)$ adl1panel/$1 [L,QSA]

#Redirect to Home 

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ includes/404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /includes/404.php
```

Comment: Comment out or remove the 3rd RewriteCond ,it is checking for existent php files.

Comment: I did that but still not working

Comment: What happes when you go to a broken link?

Comment: It is redirecting me to home page well wait i am uploading my whole code

Comment: Check now i have update my code

Comment: RewriteRule to index.php is already commented out in your htaccess, so how is the broken request going to hompage? Is this your complete htaccess or any other rules?

Comment: This is my 404 page [link](http://www.dev.ludhianalive.com/?pg=404)

Comment: No this is only htaccess file in root folder

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `.htaccess` file with this line of code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

That should do the trick.
If on  wordpress though

```
Redirect 301 /tags/something http://yoursite.com/404.php
```

Comment: I have already tried it but it doesn't work for me. My file is in inlcudes folder not in root so do i have to mention the includes folder or not?

Comment: It is still not working i have updated my question please check